# cgi-bin question

Tags: php, cgi, cgi-bin

I have access to a shared web host. 
The website installed there uses `exec()`. About 4 months ago the function was enabled, but now they have put it on the `disable_functions` list. They put `exec`, `passthru` and `shell_exec` on that list but they forgot to put `system`:) This makes me think that the server admin is not very aware on what he's doing. Anyway, they now say that those functions should have never be enabled and they wont re-enable them.

The installed website uses `exec()` to start some php scripts that would do some background work. Right now i'm looking to see if there is any other "legal" way to start those php scripts in background(i expect `system()` to work, but maybe they will disable it in the future also).
And now my simple question:
In the perdefined file structure i see a cgi-bin folder. Whats its use? From what i read on the web it is used to generate "dynamic" pages when accessed through the browser, but the server has php anyway installed, so i dont see its use.

Comment: You can use perl's system call `system("command");` very similar to php and it will be hardly blocked unless they disable cgi/perl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/cgi-bin/` is a directory where [CGI script](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Gateway_Interface) should be placed.
You can work around restrictions on exec in PHP by using CGI.

Create a file named `somefile.sh` with contents:

```
#!/bin/sh
printf "Content-Type: text/plain\n\n"
#your code here
```

This will only work if /bin/sh actually exists, and is executable (if you're not in a chroot without /bin/sh for example)

There are enough ways to get a command executed. If they disable CGI, you can continue with [SSI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Side_Includes).

Comment: I get an "Internal server error" now.
I made sh.sh, changed permissions to be executable by anyone with the content 
`#!/bin/bash
echo "dsfsdfsdf"` 
accesing it through http://site.com/cgi-bin/sh.sh

Comment: I forgot that CGI scripts need to send a Content-Type header. See updated post.